# OpenCV anonymous/guaranteed unique window

Tags: python, opencv

quite new to OpenCV so please bear with me:

I need to open up a temporary window for user input, but I need to be certain it won't overwrite a previously opened window.

Is there a way to open up either an anonymous window, or somehow create a guaranteed unique window name?

Obviously a long random string would be pretty safe, but that seems like a hack.

P.S. I'm using the python bindings at the moment, but If you want to write a response in c/c++ that's fine, I'm familiar with them.

Comment: Hi, not sure I follow. What stops you from giving a different name to the window (i.e. `imshow("window1", mat1); imshow("tempWindow", mat2)`)? Could you clarify that bit?

Comment: It's a library function. What happens if some client code has already got a window called "tempWindow"?

Comment: I see. I don't think OpenCV itself provides this functionality with its simple GUI functions, you probably have to use some kind of "hack" yourself (either a random string like you said, or have the client code supply a name as an argument etc)

Answer (score 2):

In `modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp`(or in some other file if you are not using windows - look at `void cv::namedWindow( const string& winname, int flags )` in `...src/window.cpp`) there is a function `static CvWindow* icvFindWindowByName( const char* name )` which probably is what you need, but it's internal so authors of OpenCV for some reason didn't want other to use it(or doesn't know someone may need it).

I think that the best option is to use system api to find whether a window with specific name exists.
Eventually use something that is almost impossible to be a window name, for example current time in ms + user name + random number + random string(yeah i know that window name  "234564312cyriel123234123dgbdfbddfgb#$%grw$" is not beautiful).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a possible solution myself:

A few simple wrappers around imshow and namedWindow allow the list of all current window names to be recorded in a global variable.

```
window_list = []
def new_window(name=None):
    if name == None:
        i=0
        while str(i) in window_list:
            i = i+1
        name = str(i)
    if name not in window_list:
        window_list.append(name)
    cv2.namedWindow(name)        #always create the window, in case it's been manually closed
                                 #does nothing if window is already open
    return name

def img_show(img, name=None):
    name = new_window(name)
    cv2.imshow(name, img)
    return name
```

A call to img_show without a name provides an incremental default name.

This is vaguely similar behaviour to what one gets in IDL. Obviously this isn't the most robust solution and requires that all code uses these wrappers, but it works for my needs for now.